# Navigate back to Home Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I've requirement for application to set a `Button`in every activity to go back to `HomeActivity`but I should **Not Reload** the content for it, so I need to re-use the instance I already have of `HomeActivity`, how I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running. For example, consider a task
>   consisting of four activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity()
>   with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then B
>   will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting
>   order: A, C, D, B. This flag will be ignored if
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.

Comment: Be sure that you put your AsyncTask calls, or anything else you use to initialize the class, in onCreate() instead of onResume().  Unless Android garbage collected the instance the activity should load right back up.  It might reload though if the activity was garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, i thought this would be complicated, you made my day :)

Comment: @dbaugh, this FLAG is the same as you finish() the current Activity, and go back to Previous Activity, isnt it (convention)?

Answer (score 1):

I used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for home button in my activities. If you have your `HomeActivity` already in application stack, this flag causes close of all activities above your `HomeActivity`. It depends if you need to reorder `HomeActivity` to front (Back button will return you back to activity where you clicked home) or you want to close all activities that are above `HomeActivity` (like clicking back until I'm in `HomeActivity`, in my case Back button closes application from my home activity).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP